# error php Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "PHPMailer" not found in al enviar un correo

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

trato de realizar la forma de encontrar el error al llamar a mi class
phpmailer estoy enviando el correo
pero me sale error
ya me servia pero ahora ya no me sirve

nose que pueda ser

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "PHPMailer" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\CMG_Productivo\contactos.php:16 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\CMG_Productivo\contactos.php on line 16

aqui el codigo hasta la linea 16

```
<?php

require ("PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php");
require ("PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php");
require ("PHPMailer/src/Exception.php");
require 'PHPMailer/vendor/autoload.php';


$name=$_POST['name'];
    $subject=$_POST['subject'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $message=$_POST['message'];
    $Telefono=$_POST['Telefono'];

   
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
```

estas son las dependencias que tengo instaladas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

archivo
PHPMailer.php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu llamado al autoload debería antes de cualquier otro require

Comment: ya lo puse pero me sigue apareciendo el mismo error

Comment: Una pregunta ¿No deberias ser `PHPMailer\src\PHPMailer` en tu namespace?

Comment: lo agrege asi pero me sigue apareciendo Unexpected 'Unknown'php